# Chosson and Kallah Stand with backs facing the Audience

Tags: wedding

Ive seen a Sefardi Wedding where the Chosson and Kallah stood with their backs 
facing the audience,  The bride standing to the right of the groom.

Where is the source of this Minhag?

(and whats the reason behind it?)

Comment: At my (Ahkenaz) wedding, almost 50 years ago, the rav had us standing with our backs to the audience. I do not think that it was a Sfardi issue.

Comment: The custom is that the bride & groom face Jerusalem; irrelevant of where the crowd is standing. But I cannot find a source for that now, so it's simply a comment.

Comment: I was shown that Rav Eli Mansour calls it a Sefardic Practice

Comment: At my wife and my wedding, (As you can see, my wife comes first, an not only b/c of grammar :-) our backs faced the audience. Part of the reason was to face the Aron Kodesh. Another reason was more practical for us and the rabbi. We both decided that facing the audience would be distracting to us, and would divert our *kavanah* of the ceremony, itself. Perhaps, either reason that I mentioned may be a factor? It would help if you could link a source to Chacham Mansour's comment on this. I'm unfamiliar with Sefardi practice on this, and it's been a while since I'v been to a Sefardi wedding.

Comment: Why do you think this is a Minhag and not just the way it happened there?

Comment: RABBI MANSOURS WEDDING GUIDE> http://www.dailyhalacha.com/media/Syrian_Sephardic_Wedding_Guide.pdf

Answer (score 6):

I was told by a Yekkish (German-Jewish) rabbi that backs-to-the-crowd is the German custom because the Talmud says you don't just walk into the city street and proclaim marriage to someone. (רב מנגיד דמקדש בשוקא). In that spirit, turning their backs to the crowd gives the couple some measure of privacy and makes it not "in the city street."

Comment: Didn't fully understand that, either way you're in front of the audience?

Answer (score 5):

HaRav Hershel Schachter, shalita, ([Kiddushin 5777 Shiur #58](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/869745/Rabbi%20Hershel%20Schachter/Kiddushin%20#58%20-%20Chazarah%20#9)) quotes the Yekkish Minhag to stand with the couple's backs facing the audience as a means of avoiding being considered Mekadesh beShuk. He notes how the Poskim, however, don't take this into consideration.
For example, the below Kenesset HaGedolah:

## כנסת הגדולה הגהות בית יוסף אבן העזר סימן סא אות ד

> יש מעמידים החתן והכלה לצד מערב ופניהם כנגד מזרח, והטעם שיהיו פניהם נגד
> ארון הקודש, והמברך מצדד עצמו ופניו למזרח. ויש מעמידים חתן וכלה לצד
> דרום דאמרינן הרוצה להחכים ידרים. ויש מעמידים חתן וכלה לצד צפון, כי
> כשמעמידים אותה לצד דרום אז הכלה קרובה טפי לארון הקודש מהחתן שצריכה
> לעמוד בימינו, לכך מעמידים אותה לצד צפון וסומכין נמי על הא דאמר מי
> שרוצה להתעשר יצפין. הר"ם מינץ סימן ק"ט. ובדרשות מהרי"ל כת' אחוריהן
> לצפון ופניהם לדרום, ובזמנינו זה אין אנו מקפידין ע"ז.‏

In [Nefesh HaRav (pg. 257)](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?64100&pageid=P0265), he writes that Rav Soloveitchik, was makpid that they should face Mizrach. He also said in shiur that Rav Hutner started a Minhag that the Chattan should face the audience and not the rabbi, so people should realize the Chattan is performing the marriage and the Mesader Kiddushin is just a spectator, unlike how a priest officiates at a Christian wedding. However, in [MiPninei HaRav (pg. 274)](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?64101&pageid=6410100274), he depicts how, at two different weddings in the same hall, within a month of each other, Rav Soloveitchik would have the couple stand facing Mizrach, while Rav Moshe Feinstein would have them stand facing the crowd.

With respect to the bride standing to the groom's right:

## כנסת הגדולה הגהות בית יוסף אבן העזר סימן סא אות ג

> צריך להעמיד החתן לשמאל הכלה כדי שתהיה הכלה לימין החתן. הר"ם מינץ סימן
> ק"ט וכן נהגו בקושט' רבתי. ושמעתי הטעם משום דכתיב נצבה שגל לימינו. וכ"כ
> בדרשות מהרי"ל ז"ל. ופה תירייא היו נוהגין להעמיד החתן לימין הכלה,
> ומנעתי מנהג זה ונהגתי להעמיד הכלה לימין החתן.‏

See also Yalkut Yosef (Sova Semachot 1:6:5) who quotes the various opinions and sources for each of the opinions and paskens that it's proper for the Kallah to stand at the right of the Chattan, just as Rav Ovadia always practiced.

## ילקוט יוסף שובע שמחות א הערות פרק ו' - סדר עריכת הקידושין סעיף ה

> יש אומרים שהכלה עומדת לימין החתן. ויש שאין מקפידים בזה אחר החורבן.
> והנכון הוא לנהוג להעמיד הכלה לימין החתן.
>
> הערה:
>
> ### שהכלה צריכה לעמוד לימין החתן
>
> טעם המנהג שהכלה עומדת לימין החתן
> הוא על שם הפסוק (תהלים מה) נצבה שגל לימינך בכתם אופיר. ופרש"י, אשתך
> תתיצב לימינך. ועוד, נצבה שגל לימינך סופי תיבות כלה. וכן כתב הרוקח
> (סימן שנא). וכן הוא בספר מטה משה (הלכות הכנסת כלה אות ד'). וכן כתב
> בשו"ת מהר"ם מינץ (סימן קט), והובא בכנסת הגדולה (סימן סא הגהות בית יוסף
> סק"ג), דצריך להעמיד החתן לשמאל הכלה, כדי שהכלה תהיה לימין החתן. וכן
> כתב בדרשות מהרי"ל.   אולם בסידור בית עובד (דינים השייכים לברכת
> הנישואין אות ב') כתב בשם הרב יד אהרן, ששמע משם רבינו האר"י ז"ל שזהו
> קודם החורבן, אבל בזמננו זה, אחר חורבן בית המקדש, צריך להעמיד החתן
> בימין הכלה על דבר הכתוב באיכה (ב, ד) השיב ימינו אחור. ע"כ. ובשדי חמד
> חלק ז' (עמוד 454) כתב, ואני הדל איני מקפיד בזה, ופעם אחת בעת סידור
> הקידושין אחד הלומדים שבעיר מפני הכבוד לא העיר לי על מה שלא הקפדתי בזה,
> ואחר כך שאל על זה, ובאמת שבספר בית עובד כתב בשם הרב יד אהרן שהביא בשם
> האר"י ז"ל, שזהו קודם החורבן, אבל בזמנינו זה צריך להעמיד החתן בימין
> הכלה על דרך השיב אחור ימינו. וכתב בשדי חמד, ופשיטא לי דאילו הרב כנסת
> הגדולה ראה דברי האר"י ז"ל היה מחזיק כן, ולכל הפחות אין למחות ביד
> הנוהגים כן, ואין להקפיד על ימין שהוא שמאל, עד ישקיף ה' השקפה לטובה,
> וירם ימינו. ע"ש. וכן העלה בשו"ת ישכיל עבדי חלק ח' (סימן ה' אות ב')
> וכדברי השדי חמד הנ"ל. ועיין בשו"ת רביד הזהב (לידידינו הרה"ג רבי דוד
> ברדא שליט"א, חלק אבן העזר סימן ה') שהביא מה שכתב בספר חסד לאברהם
> למהר"א אזולאי ז"ל, בזה"ל: ודע, כי אין ראוי שתשב הנקבה לימין בעלה אלא
> בשמאל, אמנם בשעת החופה בזמן שאומרים השבע ברכות באותה שעה צריך דוקא
> שהכלה תהיה נצבת לימין החתן דכתיב נצבה שגל לימינך. ע"כ. ומבואר להדיא
> מלשונו הטהור שבשעת החופה הכלה צריכה לעמוד לימין החתן. וזה שלא כדברי
> רבינו האר"י ז"ל, דסבירא ליה איפכא, דבשעת החופה צריך להעמיד החתן דוקא
> לימין הכלה.   ומרן אאמו"ר שליט"א מנהיג שהכלה עומדת לימין החתן, על שם
> הפסוק נצבה שגל לימינך.   ובדרשות מהרי"ל הנ"ל כתב עוד, שאם עורכים החופה
> בבית הכנסת מעמידים החתן והכלה לצד מערב ופניהם כלפי המזרח, והטעם כדי
> שיהיו פניהם כלפי ארון הקודש. ע"ש. ובקצור שלחן ערוך (סימן קמז) כתב,
> שמוליכין את החתן תחת החופה ומעמידים אותו פניו למזרח, והחזן מנגן כמנהג
> המקום, והשושבינות מוליכות את הכלה, והשושבינים ואנשים חשובים הולכים
> לקראתה, וכשמתקרבים אליה חוזרים לאחוריהם לחופה. והשושבינות מביאין את
> הכלה ומסבבין עמה ז' פעמים. ויש מקומות ג' פעמים. ומעמידין את הכלה לימין
> החתן, והמברך מצדד את עצמו ופניו למזרח. ע"כ. וזהו לפי מנהג האשכנזים
> שהכלה מסובבת את החתן כמה פעמים כנז'. והטעם למנהגם מבואר בתשב"ץ, שהוא
> משום שחתן דומה למלך מה מלך חיילים מקיפים אותו, אף חתן שושבינים מקיפין
> אותו. מה מלך שולחין לו מנות, אף חתן שולחין לו מנות. וטעם ג' פעמים, הוא
> כנגד כי יקח איש אשה ובא אליה ושנאה, וכי יקח איש אשה ובעלה, וכי יקח איש
> אשה חדשה, רמז ג' מסירות, על כן מוסרין לו הכלה ג' פעמים. [טעמי
> המנהגים].

Comment: Hi MDjavaheri, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for this on point answer. Be sure to check out our [tour]. I hope to see you around :)

Comment: I too wish to thank you for the very fine answer, and hope that you keep contributing in the future.

Answer (score 3):

[Nitei Gavriel Nisuin1 - 17:13:24](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46545&st=&pgnum=130) says in the name of Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 147:5, Aruch Hashulchan 62:9 and others that the Chasan and Kallah should face East (Mizrach). Perhaps the Chupa was set in such a way that facing East caused them to stand with their backs to the crowd.

I was at a Chasuna where Rabbi Azriel Chaim Goldfein Zatzal officiated. He had the Chasan and Kallah stand with their backs to the crowd. They were not facing East nor were they facing Eretz Yisrael. When I asked him about this after the Chupa he told me that this was the Minhag in Lita which was done in Telshe.

Comment: Rabbi Azriel Chaim Goldfein case was where facing East caused them to stand with their backs to the crowd?

Comment: @Moshe: No. They were facing away from the crowd and not facing East.

Comment: he didn't explain the minhag! That was my question- whats the reason behind it....

Comment: @Moshe: You asked Where is the source, not the reason behind the source. My answer, answers your question. If you have another question http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: You're right....